# как синхронизировать гугл календарь

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, google-calendar

я знаю имейл календаря в который нужно вписать события, как это сделать программна через .net?
Допустим я запрашиваю доступ моего приложения к чужому календарю, то есть пользователь входит в свой аккаунт и переходит по предложенной ссылке. Вот как работать с календарем, как его получить?

Comment: Вот [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26474294)

Comment: Программна чтобы писать события в google calendar нужно использовать его API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet. Тогда как чтобы просто получить события из него можно использовать формат .ICS(загрузка по  ссылке доступной для всех, можно найти в настройках календаря). Сформулируйте более конретно вашу проблему и тогда вам помогут.